# Passing a Different button in Command Parameter Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, commandparameter

Suppose, the followings are two buttons resides in a wpf user control.

```
<Button x:Name="Option"  VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Command="{Binding Path=OptionsButtonClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

<Button x:Name="validity"  UseLayoutRounding="true"
            Command="{Binding Path=ValidityButtonClickCommand}">
```

In the click event of `Option` button, I am passing the button as CommandParameter in the view model. How can I pass the other(`validity`) button in the commandparameter rather than the `Option` button for the same event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use element name:

```
<Button x:Name="Option"  VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    Command="{Binding Path=OptionsButtonClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=validity}">
```